# Is there any way to encrypt content in clipboard?

Tags: security, encryption, copy-paste

Is there any way to encrypt content in clipboard to provide more security and protection from malicious software?

Comment: How exactly would clipboard access differentiate between acceptable and malicious access then?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about Apple products.

Comment: And: Is this a "is there an application which allows me to" or a "how would I develop such an application" question?

Answer (score 1):

Once a keylogger/trojan/etc. managed to run on your system，encrypting the clipboard techniques don't protect your system. 
Preventing evil code from running on your system in the first place is a much better approach.